# Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++

I have a program that generates a single random character, using the `randomCharacter` function, and random strings, using the `randomString` function. The latter utilises the former, and `breedWithMutation` uses `randomCharacter` to probabilistically mutate a representation of a gene sequence.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

typedef boost::mt19937 randAlgorithm;

int mutationsPerGeneration = 100;
double probabilityOfMutation = 0.05;
string potentialAlleles = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
size_t numberOfAlleles = potentialAlleles.size();

double random01(randAlgorithm & engine)
{
  boost::uniform_real<double> u01;
  return u01(engine);
}

int randomInteger(randAlgorithm & engine, size_t min, size_t max) {
  boost::uniform_int<> minmax(min, max);
  return minmax(engine);
}

string randomCharacter(randAlgorithm & engine, string charSet, size_t charSetSize) {
  return charSet[randomInteger(engine, 0, charSetSize)];
}

string randomString(randAlgorithm & engine, size_t length, string charSet, size_t charSetSize) {
  string s;
  s.reserve(length);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    s.append(randomCharacter(engine, charSet, charSetSize));
  }
  return s;
}

string breedWithMutation(randAlgorithm & engine, string originalGenome, size_t genomeSize) {
  string mutatedGenome;
  mutatedGenome.reserve(genomeSize);
  double mutationDraw;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < genomeSize; i++) {
    mutationDraw = random01(engine);
    if (mutationDraw < probabilityOfMutation) { //The allele undergoes mutation
      mutatedGenome.append(randomCharacter(engine, potentialAlleles, numberOfAlleles));
    }
    else {
      mutatedGenome.append(originalGenome[i]);
    }
  }
  return mutatedGenome;
}
```

However, when I build the application, I get these errors:

```
    main.cpp: In function ‘std::string randomCharacter(randAlgorithm&, std::string, size_t)’:
main.cpp:31:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
main.cpp:31:55: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
main.cpp: In function ‘std::string breedWithMutation(randAlgorithm&, std::string, size_t)’:
main.cpp:53:45: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
main.cpp:53:45: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::append(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> = std::basic_string<char>]’
```

The line numbers in the errors don't line up perfectly, I realise, but the first two errors refer to the only line in `randomCharacter`, and the third and fourth errors refer to this line: `mutatedGenome.append(originalGenome[i]);` in `breedWithMutation`. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `char` and `string` are distinctly different types. One cannot implicitly convert a `char` value to a `string` (as you are trying to do in `randomCharacter`).

You could change the return type of `randomCharacter` to be `char` instead of `string`, though that may require changes elsewhere too (I haven't reviewed your code in detail).

Comment: On my part, it was a poor choice of function names. Can I append a single `char` to a `string`? I realise that they are distinctly different types; I had named `randomCharacter` as I did because it returns only a single letter (character in the layman sense, not in the C++ sense).

Wait, does `string[index]` return a `char` or a `string` type? Is that the problem?

Comment: @pythonscript The return type of `string[index]` would be a char. And this did cause your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change the return type of `randomCharacter()` to `char`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an *invalid conversion to `const char`,* it's an *invalid conversion to `const char*`.*  Strings in plain C are just arrays of characters, or `const char*`s.  So, you're using a single character where you should be using a string.

To examine one instance: You've set up `randomCharacter()` to return a C++ string, but in actuality, you're trying to return a single character from `charSet`.  It makes more sense to me for you to make the function return a `char`, but that's your decision to make.